# HTML elements are not loading on mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

A page is loading everything correctly in Chrome but not in firefox. Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how can i get rid of it?

Check This [**Link**](http://www.rectangle.com.bd/all_projects.html) on both chrome and firefox.

**Chrome:** [image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

HTML :

```
<div class="container archo-all-projects-container">
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h4 class="archo-all-projects-header">All Projects</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="argo-project-list">

    <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12"><h5 class="archo-project-type-header">Architecture</h5></div></div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3 ">
            <div class="archo-project-item">

                <div class="archo-project-item-title">
                    <a href="project.html"><h5>Project Title</h5></a>
                </div>
                <div class="archo-project-item-image">
                    <a href="project.html"><img src="asset/images/project-thumnail/1.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-3 ">
            <div class="archo-project-item">

                <div class="archo-project-item-title">
                    <a href="project.html"><h5>Project Title</h5></a>
                </div>
                <div class="archo-project-item-image">
                    <a href="project.html"><img src="asset/images/project-thumnail/1.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 ">
            <div class="archo-project-item">

                <div class="archo-project-item-title">
                    <a href="project.html"><h5>Project Title</h5></a>
                </div>
                <div class="archo-project-item-image">
                    <a href="project.html"><img src="asset/images/project-thumnail/1.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 ">
            <div class="archo-project-item">

                <div class="archo-project-item-title">
                    <a href="project.html"><h5>Project Title</h5></a>
                </div>
                <div class="archo-project-item-image">
                    <a href="project.html"><img src="asset/images/project-thumnail/1.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .archo-project-type-header{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .8;
    padding: 15px;
}
.archo-all-projects-container>.argo-project-list>.row{


}
.archo-all-projects-container .argo-project-list{
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.archo-all-projects-container .archo-all-projects-header{
    background: #fff;
    opacity: .8;
    padding: 15px;
}
.archo-all-projects-container .archo-project-item{
    background: #2b2b2b;
    margin-bottom: 15px;


}


.archo-all-projects-container .archo-project-item-image{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.archo-all-projects-container .archo-project-item-title{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.archo-all-projects-container .archo-project-item-image a,.archo-all-projects-container .archo-project-item-title a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.archo-all-projects-container .archo-project-item-image a:hover,.archo-all-projects-container .archo-project-item-title a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}






.archo-all-projects-container .archo-all-project-title{
    background: #000;
}



.archo-project-item .archo-project-item-title{
    color:#fff;
}



/*testing down*/
.archo-all-projects-container {

    /*background: #fff;*/
    bottom: 168px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 75px;
    position: absolute;


}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BTs4p/) is showing correct in both chrome and firefox

Comment: Any errors in the console?  Do you see the elements in the source code?

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: There are no errors and the elements is shown in firebug.

Comment: Could not paste all of it. Just pasted the elements and css which is troubling. @JasonP

Comment: Your page source doesn't have a `DOCTYPE`. Even if it isn't causing the issue, you should put `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your page source to ensure proper browser compatibility.

Comment: added it. @ajp15243 but no luck.

Comment: It looks like a `z-index` problem, or maybe the slideshow, because the 1st second they're visible

Comment: IE also works well! What if itz a bug in firefox. Did you try some other versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code $('body').outerHeight() results with 0. It is because you are using absolute positioning of elements. While you do this, body element will always have 0px height because it does not contain any element that will expand its height.
You can try set width: 100% on body element. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the javascript. With Firefox, I disabled javascript (using Web Developer toolbar) and refreshed the page. The elements didn't disappear.

Disable your JavaScript includes one by one until it works, then you know what the offending file is, and can use an alternate solution or fix it.

Comment: Got the problem 



`$('.argo-project-list').slimscroll({
            height: $('body').outerHeight() - $('.argo-project-list').offset().top - 75

        });` 


But how to use it without any hastle?

Answer (score 0):

You have a javascript plugin adding `height:0` to the `.slimScrollDiv` div.

Comment: That `.slimScrollDiv` is auto pushed by slimscroll.js . What can i do?

Comment: @Sujit `$('body').outerHeight() - $('.argo-project-list').offset().top - 75` is returning -216, this is your issue.

Comment: Got the issue. But how to alternate the `.offset()` to get the height from the top of the page? @Jono20201